# Pandas Series - set data between date ranges to a constant

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a very simple problem which might be a bit long-winded to explain but I'll do my best.

I have a pandas Series `daily` data which has an entry for each day and a corresponding value of False (see daily in code below).

I have two other Series objects, `start` and `end`, which hold dates such that `(start[i], end[i])` forms a date range pair. I would then like to set the values in daily that are between (start[i], end[i]) to True. Here is my code snippet to get a setup but I then don't know how to apply the date pairs to daily:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
daily = pd.Series(False, pd.bdate_range("20150101", "today", freq="D"))
monthly = pd.Series(False, pd.bdate_range("20150101", "today", freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(9))

start = [i+pd.DateOffset(random.choice([1,2,3,4])) for i in montly.index]
end = [i+pd.DateOffset(random.choice([1,2,3,4])) for i in start]

# Now set everything in daily between (start[i], end[i]) for all i.
```

A few more details - `start[i]` is earlier than `end[i]` for any `i` (i.e. what you'd expect) and `(start[i]`, end[i])`and`(start[j], end[j])` do not intersect (are disjoint).

Comment: `s` in your code is not defined

Comment: Thanks - I used s and e for start and end respectively and edited it while posting to improve readability. All fixed now btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
daily = pd.Series(False, pd.bdate_range("20150101", "today", freq="D"))
monthly = pd.Series(False, pd.bdate_range("20150101", "today", freq="MS") + pd.DateOffset(9))

start = [i + pd.DateOffset(random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])) for i in monthly.index]
end = [i + pd.DateOffset(random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])) for i in start] # removed .index


for start, end in zip(start, end):
    daily[start:end] = True
```

to get:

```
2015-01-01    False
2015-01-02    False
2015-01-03    False
2015-01-04    False
2015-01-05    False
2015-01-06    False
2015-01-07    False
2015-01-08    False
2015-01-09    False
2015-01-10    False
2015-01-11     True
2015-01-12     True
2015-01-13     True
2015-01-14     True
2015-01-15     True
2015-01-16    False
2015-01-17    False
2015-01-18    False
2015-01-19    False
2015-01-20    False
2015-01-21    False
2015-01-22    False
2015-01-23    False
2015-01-24    False
2015-01-25    False
2015-01-26    False
2015-01-27    False
2015-01-28    False
2015-01-29    False
2015-01-30    False
              ...  
2016-05-16    False
2016-05-17    False
2016-05-18    False
2016-05-19    False
2016-05-20    False
2016-05-21    False
2016-05-22    False
2016-05-23    False
2016-05-24    False
2016-05-25    False
2016-05-26    False
2016-05-27    False
2016-05-28    False
2016-05-29    False
2016-05-30    False
2016-05-31    False
2016-06-01    False
2016-06-02    False
2016-06-03    False
2016-06-04    False
2016-06-05    False
2016-06-06    False
2016-06-07    False
2016-06-08    False
2016-06-09    False
2016-06-10    False
2016-06-11    False
2016-06-12     True
2016-06-13     True
2016-06-14    False
Freq: D, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Oh, it's that simple. I didn't consider doing it with a for loop - I was looking for some DataFrames magic but the best way here is a for loop.

Comment: I guess you could build up multiple `pd.date_range` and use `DateTimeIndex.Union` to combine and then select at once, but the loop seems like a pragmatic solution that might just do it.

Comment: Yes, I agree - simple to understand too.